# Method to call the functionality of an Excel plugin file (.xll or .dll) without installing Excel?

Tags: .net, excel, .net-4.0, excel-2007, wrapper

Is there any method to call the functionality of an Excel plugin (an .xll or a .dll file), without having Excel installed?

I'm using .NET.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There may be a third-party utility that does this, but in general these .xll or .dll files work because they invoke the Excel executable.

Answer (score 1):

An xll is just a dll with certain well known functions implemented. (xlAutoOpen, etc.) If you know the signature of the function you can use LoadLibrary and GetProcAddress to call the function in C/C++. You can then call the unmanaged code from .Net.